# Waves LoAir layering

Tags: waves, lfe

How is everyone using LoAir? do you bounce it on the effect more often, or do you bounce it, and then layer it with the original? I was trying to do it before with just the "Direct" mix, but it seems to work better with the original layer and using this as a separate. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Dave Might be worth considering how many inserts you have instantiated in general - as the more plugins you have running can cause slight delay in printing your final stems. If its just 1 sound effect, maybe not, but in longer duration, sometimes, yes. You can also send the sound out a bus, pre-fader, to an FX track with LoAir and that will allow you to control how much LoAir you want in the mix with a fader instead of trying to control it with the direct/wet knob on the plug-in 

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use the LowEnder plugin rather than LoAir, and always print it 100% wet to a seperate track so we have control of balance between the original & the LFE element when it is in context/final mix

Comment: never heard of this until now. Pretty awesome and cheap.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a bunch of channels bundled together. So I'd only separate the channels, if there was a need to adjust the channels separately. Otherwise, just leave it as it is, if the mix sounds as it should.

Comment: yea, I just feel like when i left it on the insert and tried to get the mix from there, I could never really get a balance or whatever.